# Error Installing the XLConnect Package on Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, xlconnect

I followed the steps [here](https://github.com/hannarud/r-best-practices/wiki/Installing-RJava-(Ubuntu)) to install `rjava` on ubuntu. Everything worked as expected. Then I went ahead to install the `XLConnect` package without any error. But when I try loading the XLConnect package.
I got this error:

> Loading required package: XLConnectJars Error: package or namespace
>   load failed for ‘XLConnectJars’: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for
>   ‘rJava’, details: call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, …) error:
>   unable to load shared object
>   ‘/home/sdotserver1/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rJava/libs/rJava.so’:
>   **libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory** Error: package ‘XLConnectJars’ could not be loaded

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java installation cannot be located. Make sure you have a JVM installed and then reconfigure R by issuing 'sudo R CMD javareconf'.

Comment: Hello Martin, thank you for your reply. Thank you for creating a great package. I have installed jre on the ubuntu server. When I entered the `java -version`, I got this output: openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12). So I am little confused as to why XLConnect cannot find the jvm.

Comment: rJava will be detecting your Java installation, not XLConnect directly. Did you try setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable?

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I followed the steps provided on the [ubuntu stackoverflow page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java) to set JAVA_HOME in the system environment. I edited using `vim sudo /etc/environment` after which I wrote and exited. Then I see this text displayed on the screen: **2 files to edit**. But when I enter `echo $JAVA_HOME`, nothing shows on the screen.